# MySQL update values based on distinct value where a column value is the same

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a DB with over 2+mil records where I have a table `users` with these columns

```
`id`      
`UserID`
`UserType`
```

- id is an auto incremental
- UserID - contains the ID of the user
- UserType - contains either New or Returning value or sometimes N/A

What I want to achieve is to update `UserType` value to Returning if `UserID` already exists in a previous record.

like in this example:

```
 id | UserID  | UserType
-----------------------------
100 | 2258558 | New
101 | 9999999 | New
102 | 1111111 | New
103 | 2258558 | New
104 | 2258558 | New
105 | 2258558 | N/A
```

So, the query has to update row 103, 104, 105 to Returning as the `UserID` already exists on row 100.

That's fairly easy if I know

```
update users set UserType='Returning' where UserID='2258558' and id!='100'
```

The problem is that I will need to run that with thousands of unique `UserID`. So I was thinking if it is possible if somehow first distinct all unique values and then run it against the rest of rows, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need it for all UserIDs or only for the specified values?

Comment: I need it for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a join in an UPDATE. Match any row `u2` to a row `u1` that has the same user and is earlier. If such a row `u1` exists, then `u2` must not be the first one. So `u2` may be updated.

```
UPDATE users AS u1 JOIN users AS u2 
  ON u1.UserID = u2.UserID AND u1.id < u2.id
SET u2.UserType = 'Returning';
```

Note I have not tested this, so please test it yourself on some sample data to make sure it does what you want, before you apply it to your real data.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. Wondering how much time it will take to run that way for 2+ mil records?

Comment: There's no way for me to predict that, because it depends on the performance of your computer, your MySQL tuning options, the kind of data in those 2 million records, other processes running on your computer concurrently, etc. If I were to do it on my laptop (Macbook Pro 2019), I'd be surprised if it took more than 60 seconds.

Comment: I am running it on our own server and it still runs in my 40000+ sample db.. strange. But all the other queries are running quite fast.

Comment: Restarted our server... it took 7 min to complete and it works as expected. Thanks.